# Matlab Bootstrapping for a Confidence Interval that is NOT 95%

Tags: matlab

I'm aware of bootci but is there a shortcut to be able to get a confidence interval of 90% instead of 95% for bootstrapping? Otherwise I'll need to use RStudios which I've never used nor will ever use again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`bootci`](http://mathworks.com/help/stats/bootci.html) function has an optional parameter `alpha` which allows you to set the confidence. See this part of the documentation:

> `ci = bootci(nboot,{bootfun,...},'alpha',alpha)` computes the `100*(1-alpha)` bootstrap confidence interval of the statistic defined by the function `bootfun`. `bootfun` and the data that `bootci` passes to it are contained in a single cell array. `alpha` is a scalar between 0 and 1. The default value of `alpha` is `0.05`.

i.e. you just have to specify an `alpha` of `0.1` instead of `0.05`.

```
ci = bootci(...,'alpha',0.1);
```